# MVC project after deployment give- error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I am developing a small MVC 5 application.

I made it, and deploy it on at this address: [myMvcApp](http://elgibesolutions-001-site6.smarterasp.net/)
This app has a database behind and when I run it from my developing computer is running like expected. 
After deployment, when I run it on the server (link above) is going to Home/Index, and when I want to login, I insert the user and password and I get the following error:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance
>   Specified)

From this error, I understand that something is wrong with the connection string, I checked for several times and did not find something wrong.

The database is on my `SmarterAsp.Net` account, the connection string provided by `SmarterAsp` is:

```
"Data Source=SQL5007.Smarterasp.net;Initial Catalog=DB_9BCCA5_TargJoburi;User Id=DB_9BCCA5_TargJoburi_admin;Password=YOUR_DB_PASSWORD;"
```

I used CodeFirst to create my database and the connectionstring from web.config is:

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ApplicationDbContext" connectionString="Data Source=SQL5007.Smarterasp.net;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=DB_9BCCA5_TargJoburi_admin;Password=*********" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

In order for you to get this error please use the following:
user= test@test.com
password= 123456

I don't know why is running ok on my computer with the connection string which I have and on the server is saying that the connection string is not ok. 
I am not enough experience to understand what to do now, this is why I ask for your help.

this is my DbContext class:

```
using System.Data.Entity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;

namespace WebSite.Models
{
    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("ApplicationDbContext")
        {
        }

        public virtual DbSet<LocDeMunca> LocuriDeMunca { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Judet> Judete { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Oras> Orase { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Company> Companies { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<DeInteres> JobDeInteres { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<LocDeMunca>()
                .HasRequired(j=>j.Judet)
                .WithMany(d=>d.LocuriDeMunca)
                .HasForeignKey(f=>f.JudetId)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
            modelBuilder.Entity<LocDeMunca>()
                .HasRequired(j => j.Oras)
                .WithMany(d => d.LocuriDeMunca)
                .HasForeignKey(f => f.OrasId)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
            modelBuilder.Entity<LocDeMunca>()
                .HasRequired(j => j.Company)
                .WithMany(d => d.LocuriDeMunca)
                .HasForeignKey(f => f.CompanyId)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Oras>()
              .HasRequired(j => j.Judet)
              .WithMany(d => d.Orase)
              .HasForeignKey(f => f.JudetId)
              .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

            modelBuilder.Entity<DeInteres>()
                .HasRequired(j => j.LocDeMunca)
                .WithMany()
                .HasForeignKey(f => f.LocDeMuncaId)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

            modelBuilder.Entity<DeInteres>()
                 .HasRequired(j => j.User)
                 .WithMany()
                 .HasForeignKey(f => f.UserId)
                 .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);


            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }


        public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
        {
            return new ApplicationDbContext();
        }
    }
}
```

**Can you give me some advice? what to change or check?**

if you need mode info please ask.

Comment: Have you ever check these 7 steps first? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18060667/why-am-i-getting-cannot-connect-to-server-a-network-related-or-instance-speci

Comment: The database is on SmarterAsp.Net and have no options there. I made test project to check the database (with model first) and is working, but with code first is not working